# JNDI remote call - Weblogic

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, jndi

I am trying to access to some services within an application that is deployed in Weblogic through JNDI remote call.
Here is JNDI remote call:

```
    public class 
    {
      private static MyService myService = null;

      public static void main(String[] args)
      {
        try
        {
          final Context context = getInitialContext();
          System.out.println("looking up MyService...");
          myService = (MyService) context
      .lookup("java:global.MyApp-app.Component.MyServiceImp!com.company.app.domain.api.boundary.MyService");

      }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          System.out.println("error using facade bean...\n");
          e.printStackTrace();
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (myService == null)
        {
          System.out.println("No connection to the service!");
        }
      }

      private static Context getInitialContext() throws NamingException
      {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:7002");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "pass");
        return new InitialContext(env);
      }
    }
```

One thing to mention:
 - In weblogic console, when i access the managed server and then JNDI tree structure, i can see in list this "JNDI name" but when clicking on it to see the BindingName besides the BindingName i see also the following message:
 **Unexpected exception: failed to load return type; class java.lang.Object nested exception is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.company.app.domain.api.boundary.MyService **

When i run this client i get the following exception:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: remaining name: java:global.MyApp-app.Component.MyServiceImpl!com.company.app.domain.api.boundary.MyService
at weblogic.j2eeclient.SimpleContext.internalLookup(SimpleContext.java:77)
at weblogic.j2eeclient.SimpleContext.lookup(SimpleContext.java:39)
at weblogic.jndi.SimpleContext.lookup(SimpleContext.java:86)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at arberkuci.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:27)
```

Since i struggled with this so many days, i appreciate a lot any help! :-)

UPDATE

I changed value of parameter of lookup method to => "java:global/MyApp-app/Component/MyServiceImpl" and the result is:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: Context may not be null
at weblogic.j2eeclient.SimpleContext.checkForNameUnderRemoteNode(SimpleContext.java:103)
at weblogic.j2eeclient.SimpleContext.internalLookup(SimpleContext.java:68)
at weblogic.j2eeclient.SimpleContext.lookup(SimpleContext.java:39)
at weblogic.jndi.SimpleContext.lookup(SimpleContext.java:86)
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
at arberkuci.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:29)
```

Comment: The class is not available where it is needed. Classloaders are tricky and you may have to deploy shared classes inside weblogic itself for this to work. With Jndi stay with standard library classes for this exact reason

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The service(the interface)that i am trying to access through this client - is also deployed in weblogic. And as for JNDI library classes i didn't get what you said (sorry :( ). Thank you very much for you answer :-)

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can you please explain for me this part "With Jndi stay with standard library classes for this exact reason"? I struggled with this problem for so many days, so any help would contribute toward the solution. Thank you very much! :-)

Comment: You MUST understand how classloaders work, and how they work inside a web container or you will keep running into problems like this.  Essentially you must deploy the jar file with the common classes to the web container itself instead of inside your application or the code responsible for handling JNDI cannot see the classes.  If at all possible use only classes defined in the Java Standard Library instead of your own code.